# Xcode 8.3.2 keeps on building after every keystroke

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8

Whenever I try to change anything in my source files, the Xcode builds the entire project.

And since, I am in between writing the code, its obvious that there are errors (like "NSLog(@"ABC")") will throw an error if written halfway like this "NSL").

If I leave it idle, it fails for 5 to 10 times more and finally I see build succeeded. And again, when I try to change anything, it rebuilds on every keystroke and fails.

I have tried unchecking, "show live issues", "continue building after errors". Even a deep clean (command+shift+alt+k). After cleaning, its ok, but when I rebuild again, the same nut job building process continues.

This issue is not related to IBDesignables also. I have tried to uncheck "Automatically refresh views" in the storyboard and it did not work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, I can't open my storyboard as a different window, not even in a new tab. I used to have one of my windows for the source code and one for storyboard only. This made the switch between storyboard and source code much faster. But may be because of IBDesignables, its not possible anymore.

The problem is partially solved. Even if I open my storyboard now, it shows the same behavior of rebuilding again and again. But atleast, I can write my code in peace now with only source code files open in different tabs/windows.

Comment: Can you take a sysdiagnose when this is happening and file a radar with it at http://bugreport.apple.com?  Have you tried Xcode 9 to see if it is still an issue?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I don't know anything about sysdiagnose. Please elaborate....

Comment: Open Terminal and run `sudo sysdiagnose -q` to generate a sysdiagnose tarball.

Comment: When do I do this? When XCode is going haywire and rebuilding itself?

Comment: Yes.  That should give us a snapshot of what it going on.